# MongoDB : Push new item to the top of the array via findOneandUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a nodejs and mongo newbie. I want to push an item into the array which is nested into the document via findOneandUpdate, but would like to add the new item as the first element (top of the array). Here is my structure :

[image]

This works fine for adding item to the **end of the array**:

```
const newNote = await NotesBlock.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId }, { $push: { notes: { noteTitle: req.body.noteTitle, noteDetail: req.body.noteDetail } } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

As I know we can't use unshift with mongodb, but $each and $position can be used for this purpose. So, I have tried this :

```
const newNote = await NotesBlock.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId }, { $push: { notes: { $each:[noteTitle: req.body.noteTitle, noteDetail: req.body.noteDetail], $position: 0 } } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

But unfortunately, this gives me an error for the syntax.

[image: Syntax error]

I can't figure out how to avoid this and make it work. Or is this the wrong approach and there is any other way to achieve?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ $each: { noteTitle: req.body.noteTitle, ...`, that is curly braces instead of square brackets?

Comment: @tromgy Nope. Per MongoDB documentation, it should be square brackets. But still, I have tried to replace it with curly braces per your suggestion, but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Here is the official docs : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. Following was close enough, except the curly brackets that should be inside the square brackets. So I had to change this :

```
const newNote = await NotesBlock.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId }, { $push: { notes: { $each:[noteTitle: req.body.noteTitle, noteDetail: req.body.noteDetail], $position: 0 } } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

To this :

```
const newNote = await NotesBlock.findOneAndUpdate({ blockId: req.params.blockId }, { $push: { notes: { $each: [{ noteTitle: req.body.noteTitle, noteDetail: req.body.noteDetail }], $position: 0 } } }, { upsert: true, new: true })
```

And it works as expected now.